# Jquery menu - return json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I've created a menu from a jquery script.  The script parses a json response file and creates the menu.  That works.  However, the menu then links to a URL.  I don't want it to link to the URL, but rather get the json response from that URL and parse it. I've tried and no matter what, it always follows the URL.  Here is what I have so far:

jQuery Menu creation (working):

```
<script>
    $.getJSON('https://example.com/api/products/GetProductList/', function(data) {
        var output = '<div class="panel panel-default">';
        for (var i in data.Categories) {
            output += '<div class="panel-heading '+data.Categories[i].category_id +'"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#' + data.Categories[i].category_id + '-products">';
            output += data.Categories[i].Category + '</a></div>';
            output += '<div id="' + data.Categories[i].category_id + '-products" class="panel-collapse collapse"><div class="panel-body">';
            for (var j in data.Categories[i].Products) {
                output += '<li><a class="ProdLink" href="https://example.com/api/products/GetProductDetail/'+data.Categories[i].Products[j].product_id+'">'+data.Categories[i].Products[j].short_description + " -- " + data.Categories[i].Products[j].coins+' coins</a></li>';
            }
            output += "</div></div>";
        }
        output += "</div>";

        document.getElementById("accordion").innerHTML = output;
    });
</script>
```

This creates a menu with an item such as this

```
<a class="ProdLink" href="https://example.com/api/products/GetProductDetail/2">Test Item</a>
```

To parse the data from this URL I've tried:

```
     <script>
 $('#accordion').on('click','a.ProdLink',function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("href");

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        var output = '<div>';
        for (var i in data) {
            output += data[i].full_description;
        }
        output += "</div>";

        document.getElementById("itemdata").innerHTML = output;
    });});

</script>
```

But this isn't working.  Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: This excerpt appears to be missing a closing brace and parentheses `});` before your closing `</script>` tag. Is that the case in the actual code?

Comment: That was a typo on my part here, the actual code was correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending links dynamically, so use **[event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** to handle events on dynamic elements, here `a.ProdLink`.

```
$('#accordion').on('click','a.ProdLink',function(event){
  ...
});
```

Also, this line suggests`ProdLink` is the `id`, change it to `class` t avoid duplicate IDs

```
output += '<li><a id="ProdLink" ...
```

And as [cloudworks points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129674/jquery-menu-return-json-data#comment50271150_31129674) the click function should be closed with apt paranthesis.

Comment: I've tried this, but it's still forwarding to "https://example.com/api/products/GetProductDetail/2" and not executing the script instead.

Comment: Are you sure  `ProdLink` is the class attribute?

Comment: Yes changed id="ProdLink" to class="ProdLink"

Comment: I've updated to show the current state.  Still not working though.

Comment: Try using $(document) instead of $('#accordion') . Try adding a debugger to the code to check whether click fires

Comment: When I change it to $(document) it says "null" in the itemdata div.  So it's executing the click, but not returning the data from the json

Comment: So the server is returning null here. Check the API for details. Are you getting network request errors?

Comment: The API works.  If I type the URL https://example.com/api/products/GetProductDetail/2 in directly, I get the json response

Comment: Try `alert(url)` after the line `var url = $(this).attr("href");` and check your network tab in browser for errors.

Comment: Then the problem lies in the callback. Is there a div with ID as `itemData` or it is a class?, please post your html.

Comment: `<div id="itemdata"></div>` is the div.  I don't think it's a problem with them html.  Maybe it's not parsing the json correctly?

Comment: Nermind, the db was returning a null on the one product because there was no description.  The rest work fine.  Thank you.